# Why am I getting large p95 response times on a simple Go web service?

Tags: go, response

The service simply reads query params and creates an object and returns it to the requester. Yet at times I'm getting 200ms response times. It feels like there's some resource that's not being cleaned up correctly or something, but I don't even know where I should be looking.

Here's what I've tried:

- Disabling Keep-Alive. There's no additional resources loaded here, so I'm not sure I needed it.
- Setting the response `Connection` header to close. Same reasons.
- Increased the server's ulimit open files to 65535.

Open File Descriptor Settings:

/etc/sysctl.conf

```
# increase max open files
fs.file-max = 65536
```

/etc/security/limits.conf:

```
*               soft    nproc           65535
*               hard    nproc           65535
*               soft    nofile          65535
*               hard    nofile          65535
```

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "net/http"
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    // router
    router := mux.NewRouter()

    // v1 router
    v1router := router.PathPrefix("/v1").Subrouter()
    v1router.HandleFunc("/resource", createResource).Methods("GET")

    // server config
    server := &http.Server{
        Addr:         ":8080",
        ReadTimeout:  time.Millisecond * 500,
        WriteTimeout: time.Millisecond * 100,
        IdleTimeout:  time.Millisecond * 500,
        Handler:      router,
    }

    server.SetKeepAlivesEnabled(false)

    // start server
    server.ListenAndServe()
}


type Resource struct {
    Id string
    Name string
}

func createResource(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    // connection header
    response.Header().Set("Connection", "close")
    defer request.Body.Close()

    // get query params
    params := request.URL.Query()

    // create resource
    resource := Resource{
        Id: "testid",
        Name: params.Get("name"),
    }

    // convert resource to string
    resourceStr, _ := json.Marshal(resource)

    response.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    _, _ = response.Write([]byte(resourceStr))
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can check the reason by removing the ```mux``` library or just returning a simple string?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "checking the reason" is there something I should be looking for?

Comment: I think I understand what you're staying. Further eliminate variables by reducing the application to it's most simple state. Yea that's fair, I could probably reduce it further, but I'm still surprised to see this kind of poor performance on such a simple request.

Comment: Yes, I have not used the ```mux``` library, but you may be able to further check the performance loss in this way, ```mux``` or go itself

Comment: What else is running on the server machine?

Comment: @Luna alright I'll remove mux and the json object and see if anything changes.

Comment: @Flimzy nothing else is installed it's an AWS c5.large instance with the base Amazon AMI image.

Comment: The fact that it's on AWS means that it is shared with any untold number of other services, so erratic performance is to be expected. To get a _meaningful_ test, run it on a dedicated machine, with nothing else happening. If you still get erratic performance, then there's actually something to investigate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because debugging shared-hosting performance is off-topic for SO.

Comment: I've tried a number of different configurations. Granted all on shared hardware, but with similar results each time. After testing on multiple different instances I don't believe it to be a hardware issue. I've continued to reduce the functionality until it's what's presented in this question. At this point, I've basically narrowed it down to one of the following being misconfigured: the Go server, libraries used in the Go server, the OS, or the load test software. I've got a plan to eliminate the load test software, but in general I'm looking for feedback in these areas.

Comment: I'll see if I can get a dedicated instance to test against and report back.